# Popup textbox on website on touchscreen monitor

Tags: browser-automation

i want a textbox to popup whenever i use my touchscreen monitor to click on a textbox on a specific website.  I would prefer not to interfere with the code of the website. Is there another way i can do this? Maybe writing it as a plugin for the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a google chrome extension, Virtual Keyboard Interface